# How to build or install freeglut on a windows machine

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I downloaded [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/).  I'm reading the installation [instructions](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/install.php).  I extracted all the files.  I see a file called configure (and configure.ac).  I opened visual studio command prompt and changed the directory to

`C:\DevStuff\OpenGL\freeglut-2.8.0`

The next step is to **configure the packages**

`./configure`

This looks like a Linux command. How am I supposed to complete this kind of a build on a windows 7 machine?  I have visual studio 2010 ultimate ed.

**UPDATE**

I found the VS2010 directory and successfully performed a build.  I need `freeglut_static.lib`, which did not come out of this build.  The output directory

`..\..\lib\x86\Debug` contains only one lib file, freeglut.lib.

I suspect I need the makefile, but I really don't know.  This lib is required for OpenGL Superbible [sample projects](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/fourthEdition.htm).  In the sample projects when I try to run it a compilation error:

```
error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'freeglut_static.lib' C:\DevStuff\OpenGL\SB-WinwBin\SuperBible4\examples\projects\microsoft\chapt01\block\LINK    block
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How am I supposed to complete this kind of a build on a windows 7 machine?

[MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys).

Or use the VS2010 solution in the `VisualStudio\2010` directory.

**EDIT**:

If you need `freeglut_static.lib` use the `Debug_Static` or `Release_Static` configurations in `freeglut.sln`.

Comment: The Superbible project still doesn't build, due to the same error. But, this does answer my initial question on how to build freeglut.

Answer (score 5):

*Info for anyone trying to get the [samples](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/fourthEdition.htm) for 4th ed OpenGL superbible to work on a Windows box.*

The website comes with everything you need.  No need to build or install freeglut seperately.  It's just that the projects are not configured correctly.  For visual studio 2010, here's the fix for the first project entitled block:

1. Right click the project > properties > VC++ Directories > **Library
   Directories** (not Include directories) > Add a link to the
   freeglut_static.lib which comes with the download.  E.G. `C:\DevStuff\OpenGL\SB-WinwBin\SuperBible4\examples\src\shared;`
2. If you build now, you will get a new error regarding inability to link LIBC.lib.  With the project properties still open go to Linker > Input > Ignore Specific Default Libraries > click the dropdown arrow > click `<Edit...>` > type `LIBC.lib` and click ok.

Now everything should build just fine.

Comment: I finally got a successful build because of this answer. I want to make a note that you have to include the gltools by doing step 1: C:\SB5\Src\GLTools\include