# getting some errors after building a opengl project on vs2010

Tags: c++, opengl

Code from Opengl Superbible (4th ed).
After adding the *.h* and *.cpp* files in the project and the *LIBC.LIB* ignored, errors appeared:

```
1>freeglut_static.lib(freeglut_display.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __iob referenced in function _glutSwapBuffers
1>freeglut_static.lib(freeglut_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob
```

These errors appear only when I try to use `glLoadTGA()` (defined in *gltools.h*) from *gltools*. If anyone has some ideas about it, it would be great...

Comment: Add this to your cpp file: extern "C" { FILE _iob[3] = {__iob_func()[0], __iob_func()[1], __iob_func()[2]}; }

Answer (score 0):

> ignore the LIBC.LIB

Why? That's most likely the reson for the error. Unless you're doing lowest system level work, you need a libc.

Comment: I just followed this page, two steps there... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298963/how-to-build-or-install-freeglut-on-a-windows-machine what are those two steps' func